# What's the correct way to pass changed value of variable?

Tags: swift, variables, parameter-passing

So this is my code as you can see I'm trying to change the value of `activitylevel` if the image of a button is the same it all works fine and it changes the value, but when I try to use it down in the `CaloriesCalculator` function at `let tde = activity * bmr` activity still equals `0.0`. I know that I can save it with `UserDefaults`, but that doesn't seem the correct way to me. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
class MenuController: UIViewController {

    var calGoal: Double = 0.0
    var activitylevel: Double = 0.0

    @IBOutlet weak var Weight: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Height: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Age: UITextField!

    @IBAction func ActivityLevelButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if let ButtonImage = LightlyActive.image(for: .normal),
            let Image = UIImage(named: "LightlyActiveGreen"),
            ButtonImage.pngData() == Image.pngData()
        {
            activitylevel = 1.375
            print(activitylevel)


        }; if let ButtonImage = Active.image(for: .normal),
            let Image = UIImage(named: "ActiveGreen"),
            ButtonImage.pngData() == Image.pngData()  {

            activitylevel = 1.55
            print(activitylevel)

        }; if let ButtonImage = VeryActive.image(for: .normal),
            let Image = UIImage(named: "VeryActiveGreen"),
            ButtonImage.pngData() == Image.pngData()  {

            activitylevel = 1.755

            print(activitylevel)

        }

    }

    @IBAction func CaloriesCalculator(_ sender: UIButton) {



        let w = Double(Weight.text!) ?? 0
        let h = Double(Height.text!)!  * 0.393701
        let a = Double(Age.text!) ?? 0
        let bmr = 66 + (6.23 * w) + (12.7 * h) - (6.8 * a)
        let activity = activitylevel
        let tde = activity * bmr
        calGoal = tde
        print(activitylevel)

}
```

Comment: You are not editing the value of `activitylevel ` in `CaloriesCalculator` method... So what is your expectation?! Tips: 1) For naming function, you should follow the *lower camel case* convention (`caloriesCalculator ` instead of `CaloriesCalculator`). 2) Preferably, for such a case, your function should start with *verb* instead (`calculateCalories` instead of `caloriesCalculator`).

Comment: I assume both functions are in the same class so that it is the same `activitylevel` property in both cases?

Comment: Also, using `pngData()` to identify a button looks like massive overkill. What about setting a tag value for each button and then comparing the tag against a three constants?